# Azure wildcard domains and custom "Web Site not found" page

Tags: http-status-code-404, azure-web-app-service, wildcard-subdomain

We have a app set up with a wildcard domain *.mysite.com

We also have url rewrite rules to redirect www.*.mysite.com to *.mysite.com

As far as I can tell there is no way to map 2nd level subdomains to an azure app. You get a nasty blue "Web Site not found" page.

Is there any way to better handle 2nd level domains? Any way of mapping them to a default site?

Is there a way to customise the 404 "Web Site not found" page?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
So it seems that azure doe not support 2nd level subdomains - bummer.

Is there a way to route 2nd level domains differently to 1st level subdomains? A work around would be to have *.example.com to got to IP one and *.*.example.com go to IP two. Is there a way to do this? We are using route 53 for DNS.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to better handle 2nd level domains? Any way of mapping them to a default site?

AFAIK, Azure does **not support** wildcard custom domains currently. Single wildcard domain (eg `*.mysite.com`) is well supported, however eg `www.*.mysite.com` is not supported currently. If you want this feature added, you can locate to here to vote on the [issue](https://apac01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeedback.azure.com%2Fforums%2F169385-websites%2Fsuggestions%2F7026845-support-double-wildcard-custom-domains&data=02%7C01%7C%7C5525536ca3954bb1c4fa08d623497b95%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636735195844967966&sdata=pV9%2BAhpcFVeQslnEVCOElbrVotRw1c0hlksXjLm%2FMfs%3D&reserved=0).

> Is there a way to customise the 404 "Web Site not found" page?

For how to customize the 404 error page, you can take a look at the following reference.
Add or modify the `web.config` file and set the `Custom Error` Element to **On**.

```
<customErrors mode="On">  
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"/>  
</customErrors>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/618722/custom-error-page-in-Asp-Net-mvc/).

Comment: Thanks Joey, we already have custom error pages for the site, however the "web site not found" page is a generic azure error page. As the error title suggested it is not reaching our website so our custom error is never displayed. The problem is that www.*.mysite.com never reaches out app.

Comment: As I have mentioned, secondary level wildcards are not supported at all by Azure, it will get 404 error, so you could not reach your app.